# Output first matching matrix block model if condition is true

Tags: matrix

I've run into situation, where I have to loop only once, if condition has met the requirements. The condition is controlled by matrix block field `ligthswitch` which is the field in `finish`.

Matrix structure:
[image]

Actually, I've ended up doing this:

```
{% for block in entry.productSettings.type('finish') %}
   {% if block.inStock %}
      {{ block.amazonUri }}
   {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

which outputs cluster of characters: `123456`.
Bear in mind, that total count of characters is count of loops. Desire output is `1`.

Comment: Could you provide a little more information on how your matrix is structured? A screenshot would be useful!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can't something like this help you?

```
{% for block in entry.myMatrixField.type('fruits').ligthswitchField(params) %}
```

Comment: Lightswitch field is a matrix block in matrix field `fruits`.

Comment: Sorry, not understanding the question properly :)

Comment: You basically got my point at the first time. Didn't see that, after browsing through all my questions.

Answer (score 0):

I think, I've cracked it. I haven't tough of concatenating matrix block within the loop and set parameters right in the source.

```
{% for block in entry.productSettings.type('finish').inStock('1').limit(1) %}
    {{ block.amazonUri }}
{% endfor %}
```

It gives first true element in the loop.